# openapi-generator-maven-plugin not generating any test cases when the provided generatorName is spring

Tags: openapi-generator

I have an api.yml file which i used to generate restendpoint using maven generte-sources command
The source got generated in target/generated-sources but no test cases are being generated.

I have tried setting false but nothing happened

my configuration is here

```
 <plugin>
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>        
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\api.yml</inputSpec>
            <modelPackage>com.demo.model</modelPackage>
            <apiPackage>com.demo.api</apiPackage>
            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <generateApi>True</generateApi>
                <generateApiTests>True</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>True</generateModelTests>
                <validateSpec>true</validateSpec>
                <configOptions>
                 <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                 <title>swagger-codegen-demo</title>
            </configOptions>
        </configuration>
     </execution>

</executions>
```

Comment: please report the issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new instead

Comment: Maybe not related, I think validateSpec should be in configOptions...

Comment: Same here – @WilliamCheng has this been reported in the meanwhile, is there an issue or should i open one?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this question:

There is an issue on GitHub that mentions that no tests are generated.
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3318

Currently, (March 2023) there hasn't been any updates on the related PR since November 2019.